# Cardinality of 3-sylow subgroup in this group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, problem-solving, sylow-theory

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve this particular question.

> In the group $G$ of all invertible $4\times 4$ matrices with entries in the field of $3$ elements, any $3$-Sylow subgroup has what cardinality?

Cardinality of group $G$ is $80 \times 78 \times 72 \times 54$. I thought $3$-Sylow subgroup has cardinality $3^n =81$ but this is wrong .

Answer:

> $$729$$

I am not able to think any other result which I can use it here.
So, Can anyone please tell me right way to approach this question?

Thanks!!

Comment: So the order of a $p$-Sylow subgroup in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is $p^{n(n-1)/2}$. We have $n=4$ and $p=3$. So the order is $3^6=729$.

Comment: $80 \times 78 \times 72 \times 54 = 2^9 \times 3^6 \times 5 \times 13$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks I got it!!